# Automating PBI datafresh refresh after ETL process

Tags: automation, talend, powerbi-desktop

We use Talend as ETL and PBI as Dashboard tool. We have scheduled when issues must be launched, but we want to launch it after ETL loading process. Is there any way to tell to PBI it refresh dataset when ETL processes has finished?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/datasets/refresh-dataset-in-group

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Powe- Automate to ensure automatic refresh takes place for a powerBI
you can schedule it or you can make it triggered by file or token.
you need to check which version of PBI you are using & if it include Power automate feature.